# Using an LTE Dongle on a router's USB port

Tags: router, usb, tp-link

I know there are routers which support LTE/3G dongles (like the FRITZ!box by AVM). But if I have got a router, which officially does not suppport these dongles, but has got USB ports for NAT storage, can it support LTE/3G dongles with the correct software? Meaning, if I install a custom firmware, can the router support dongles then?

I'm talking about the "TP-Link Archer C9 AC1900", if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've never attempted something like this (nor do I have that hardware); I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. As long as your custom firmware supports LTE dongles; or at a minimum gave you shell access you should be able to get it connected.

Best case your custom firmware supports it and you don't have any issues.

Worst case; you get shell access to the router and have to manually get the LTE dongle to work and then configure what ever routing/failover you wanted.

Comment: I do have this hardware, and [yes, it works if the firmware supports it](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/3gdongle).

Comment: So it is **not** a hardware limitation?
Thank you for your quick reply!